# Python Dict - Multiple Instances or "Sub-Dict" Question - Adding items programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I want to create a dict in python that has a number of "sub-values" that I need to populate programatically. This dict will be used to add a document to a MongoDB database.

an idea of the dict i eventually want to use would be:

```
    host_dict = {
    'installed_applications':
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }
        {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }
}
```

what I tried to do was:

```
host_dict = {}
apps = get_installed_apps(host)
host_dict['installed_applications'] = {}
for app in apps:
    host_dict['installed_applications']['name'] = app[0]
    host_dict['installed_applications']['version'] = app[1]
    host_dict['installed_applications']['uninstall_string'] = app[2]
    host_dict['installed_applications']['install_date'] = app[3]
    host_dict['installed_applications']['install_location'] = app[4]
    host_dict['installed_applications']['publisher'] = app[5]
```

The problem is that it doesnt append each instance of application it just kept over-writing the one 'sub-dict' (is that what you'd call it?)

Comment: Your expected value for `host_dict` isn't valid Python (try it!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but `host_dict` is not a valid dictionary, what I will assume that you tried to create a dictionary with key `installed_applications` and value as a list, so it will look something like this

```
host_dict = {
    'installed_applications':
    [{
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
        {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }]
}
```

In that case, you can easily create the values by iterating over `apps`, adding required key-value pairs to a list, and then assigning that list to `installed_applications` key

```
host_dict = {}
apps = get_installed_apps(host)
host_dict['installed_applications'] = {}

#List to store list of dictionaries
li = []
#Iterate through apps
for app in apps:
    #Create a dictionary for app and append to the list
    dct = {}
    dct['name'] = app[0]
    dct['version'] = app[1]
    dct['uninstall_string'] = app[2]
    dct['install_date'] = app[3]
    dct['install_location'] = app[4]
    dct['publisher'] = app[5]
    li.append(dct)

#Assign the list
host_dict['installed_applications'] = li
```

Or making the code shorter, we can do

```
host_dict = {}
apps = get_installed_apps(host)
host_dict['installed_applications'] = {}

#List to store list of dictionaries
li = []

#List of keys for app
app_keys = ['name', 'version', 'uninstall_string', 'install_date', 'install_location', 'publisher']

#Iterate through apps
for app in apps:
    dct = {}
    #Make the dictionary
    for idx, item in enumerate(app):
        dct[app_keys[item]] = item

    li.append(dct)

#Assign the list
host_dict['installed_applications'] = li
```

Comment: Good catch - i need the list which has a dict for each. Thanks friend!

Comment: Thanks for the accept @chamber, I also added a much shorter version of the code!

Answer (score 0):

Your `host_dict` example is not a valid python structure, but you could fix this by having the `installed_applications` value as a list, so you can append items to this list, each item being a dict, like this:

```
apps = get_installed_apps(host)
host_dict = {'installed_applications': []}
for app in apps:
    new_app = {
        'name': app[0],
        'version': app[1],
        'uninstall_string': app[2],
        'install_date': app[3],
        'install_location': app[4],
        'publisher': app[5]
    }
    host_dict['installed_applications'].append(new_app)
```

In the end `host_dict['installed_applications']` will have a list where each value is an *app* dict, similiar to this:

```
host_dict = {
'installed_applications': [
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    },
    {
        'name': 'alsdfasdf',
        'version': '1',
        'installed_date': '11-11-11',
    }]
}
```